# Excel - Duplicate Data

Tags: excel, duplicates

I don't have much experience with Excel and I need to solve an issue

Our sales Excel sheet has the following

```
Product Name |  Item Sold Price |     Unit Cost     | 

Product 1          £5                     £3
Product 1          £9                     £3
Product 1          £4                     £3
Product 1          £12                    £3
Product 1          £10                    £3
```

We want to remove duplicate data and combine all duplicate items as one product and work out the average Item Sold Price.

Comment: The example data you gave above doesn't have any duplicates.

Comment: Why not use a pivot table with the sheet data as source. This will allow you to do most of the calculations that you require I think.

Comment: Read this article to see how to remove duplicates in Excel: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-d6549cf0-357a-4acf-9df5-ca507915b704

Answer (score 1):

Likely easily solved In two or three clicks with a pivot table depending on what you mean by duplicate. What would the answer be in the example you have given ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you looking for is called as "Pivot"

you can refer [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) to find out how pivot work

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want a result like this?:

```
    Product Name |   Item Sold Price           |  Unit Cost
    -------------|-----------------------------|--------------------------
    Product 1    |    AVERAGE(5, 9, 4, 12, 10) |    AVERAGE(3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

It can be done using pivot table...